# Error while multiplying decimals with variables in C++

Tags: c++, decimal

I'm a student and started learning C++ recently.I was making a GPA calculator for my juniors in C++ but I'm facing an error. When I multiply a decimal with a variable, I get the same answer every time. This happens with the decimals only. Exact integers work fine.
I get the right answer if I place the value of variable "cal" in the range of and integer.Like if I place 85, I get 12 as output but when I type the value below 85, I get 3.1 every time.

Can you point out my mistake?

Here is my starting source code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
    int main()
        {double cal,calh,c1;
        cout<< "How many marks you obtained in calculus? \n";
        cin >>cal;
        cout<<"Enter the credit hours of Calculus? \n";
        cin>>calh;
        if (cal>85 || cal==85){c1=4*calh;}
        else if (cal>80 || cal==80 || cal<85){c1=3.7*calh;}
        else if (cal>75 || cal==75 || cal<80){c1=3.3*calh;}
        else if (cal>70 || cal==70 || cal<75){c1=3*calh;}
        else if (cal>65 || cal==65 || cal<70){c1=2.7*calh;}
        else if (cal>61 || cal==61 || cal<65){c1=2.3*calh;}
        else if (cal>58 || cal==58 || cal<61){c1=2*calh;}
        else if (cal>55 || cal==55 || cal<58){c1=1.7*calh;}
        else if (cal>50 || cal==50 || cal<55){c1=1*calh;}
        else if (cal<50 || cal==49){cout<<"Sorry but you are failed in calculus.";}
        cout<<"your total gpa in calculus is "<< c1<<endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You can replace lines such as "cal>85 || cal==85" with "cal >= 85".

Comment: `(cal>80 || cal==80 || cal<85)` is the same as `(cal>=80 || cal<85)`  which cannot be false (excluding quiet NAN values).  I *think* you were trying to say `( (cal > 80) || cal==) && cal < 85)` (which is the same as `(cal >= 80 && cal < 85).  This is unnecessary because if `cal` is not less than 85, you won't even consider the test the previous branch of the elif will catch it.

Comment: I suggest you learn some debugging skills. You can use a source-level debugger such as gdb or the one in your IDE or you can add cout statements to each `if` clause.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice see this picture.
http://prntscr.com/e9en3x
the answer would be 6.9 but it is giving me the same answer for every variable.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your first two conditional lines:

```
if (cal>85 || cal==85){c1=4*calh;}
else if (cal>80 || cal==80 || cal<85){c1=3.7*calh;}
```

In the second one, you are entering in the condition for every possible value, as you are asking "any value that are greater than 80, but also any value that are lower than 85". So you will always have c1 = 3.7*calh, except if cal is superior to 85. That's why you are getting the same value everytime.

I think the problem is that you misunderstood the logic of the || operator. When you have several conditions in a if statement separated with a ||, it means that only one of the conditions needs to be true to enter the condition. If you want to keep this logic, remove the "==" and ">" tests and replace them with a ">=" one, and replace your || operator with &&.

Now let's look at your code again. There is some conditions you are repeating there. You already that you are entering the first else if cal is lesser than 85, so you don't need to verify it again. Then, in the end, you can replace

```
else if (cal>80 || cal==80 || cal<85){c1=3.7*calh;}
```

With:

```
else if(cal >=80) {c1=3.7*calh;}
```

Apply this trick everywhere, and you are done.

Comment: && is higher priority than ||, so this will be evaluated as `cal>80 || (cal==80 && cal < 85)' - which will actually work in this case, but only because the comparison against 85 is completely redundant anyway.

Comment: @MartinBonner What he should actually do is 'cal>= 80 && cal < 85'. Or simply 'cal >= 80'.

Comment: No, what he should *actually* do is `else if (cal >= 80)` - the comparison with 85 is redundant because of the elif chain.  Ah - I see you edited your comment.

Comment: @MartinBonner Eh eh, sorry. Mainly I wanted to put the "&&" part just so that the OP can understand why "||" is wrong in his particular case. But 'cal >= 80' is indeed the way to go there.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you wrote

```
else if (cal>80 || cal==80 || cal<85){c1=3.7*calh;}
```

This will match everything (*any number* is either larger than 80 **or** less than 85)

You want something like this instead

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  double cal, calh, c1;
  cout << "How many marks you obtained in calculus? \n";
  cin >> cal;
  cout << "Enter the credit hours of Calculus? \n";
  cin >> calh;
  if (cal >= 85) { c1 = 4 * calh; }
  else if (cal >= 80) { c1 = 3.7*calh; }
  else if (cal >= 75) { c1 = 3.3*calh; }
  else if (cal >= 70) { c1 = 3 * calh; }
  else if (cal >= 65) { c1 = 2.7*calh; }
  else if (cal >= 61) { c1 = 2.3*calh; }
  else if (cal >= 58) { c1 = 2 * calh; }
  else if (cal >= 55) { c1 = 1.7*calh; }
  else if (cal >= 50) { c1 = 1 * calh; }
  else { cout << "Sorry but you are failed in calculus."; c1 = 0; }
  cout << "your total gpa in calculus is " << c1 << endl;
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you made a little mistake bro. You assign 55 value to "calh". Anyways this worked for me :) Thanks :)